# Using Initial Context with Play Framework instead of Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, scala, tomcat, playframework-2.0

So I have a basic DAO class that makes a connection using an InitialContext lookup with Tomcat and Spring and it works perfectly:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();                        
initialize((DataSource) initCtx.lookup(resourceName));
```

Now, I have extended that basic DAO and am using the child class in a play framework application. The initial context lookup, however, does not work on the play application. The error says:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NotContextException: comp is not a subcontext
    at tyrex.naming.EnvContext.internalLookup(Unknown Source) ~[tyrex-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1  November 11 2003 1703]
    at tyrex.naming.EnvContext.lookup(Unknown Source) ~[tyrex-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1  November 11 2003 1703]
    at tyrex.naming.java.JavaContext.lookup(Unknown Source) ~[tyrex-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1  November 11 2003 1703]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at DatabaseFactory.<init>(DatabaseFactory.java:63) ~[Utilities-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
```

Is there anyway to use the initial context lookup function while still using the play framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play's JNDI environment is provided by an [in-memory JNDI service provider](http://tyrex.sourceforge.net/naming.html#MemoryContext). There is a Play helper class you can use to get hold of the `InitialContext` called [play.api.libs.JNDI](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/JNDI.scala). You can use this to lookup your datasource.

Using [this benchmark test app](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/tree/master/frameworks/Java/play2-java/play2-java-jpa-bonecp) as an example and adding the following action:

```
public Application extends Controller {

    ... 

    public static Result getDataSource() throws NamingException {
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) play.api.libs.JNDI.initialContext().lookup("DefaultDS");

        return ok(dataSource.toString());
    }
}
```

would lookup the datasource bound to the name `DefaultDS` in the [`application.conf`](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/master/frameworks/Java/play2-java/play2-java-jpa-bonecp/conf/application.conf#L36)

Looking at your exception, it seems like you're looking up the `InitialContext` and then resources with `java:comp/.../resourceName` in your utility library. This won't play (excuse the pun) well in your Play app out of the box. I would suggest you lookup your `DataSource` in a Play specific way, as per the example above.

Comment: Currently, I have a common Database Access object that gets the datasource using the javax.naming.InitialContext object, but that doesn't work for play. So how can I retrieve the datasource for both the spring and play object?